# Determinar cuando soportes abiertos deben cerrarse con el mismo tipo de soportes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Dada una cadena que contiene solo los caracteres '(', ')', '{', '}', '[' y ']', determine si la cadena de entrada es válida.

Una cadena de entrada es válida si:

1. Los soportes abiertos deben cerrarse con el mismo tipo de soportes.
2. Los soportes abiertos deben cerrarse en el orden correcto.

```
class Solution:

    def matchingBrackets(self, s:str, bracket) -> bool:
        lefts = ['(','{','[']
        rights = [')',']','}']
        if s[0] in lefts:
            if len(s) > 1: # is there another bracket to close the given one
                self.matchingBrackets(s[1:],s[0])
            else: # there is no more brackets, the given one won't be close
                return False
        elif s[0] in rights:
            if rights.index(str(s[0])) == lefts.index(bracket):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            print("different from brackets")
            s = s[1:]

    def isValid(self, s: str) -> bool:
        lefts = ['(','{','[']
        rights = [')','}',']']
        if len(s) <2:
            print("empty")
            return False
        if s[0] in rights or s[0] in lefts:
            bracket = s[0]
        return self.matchingBrackets(s[1:],bracket)
```

Funciona con `()` y `((` pero no `)}{({))[{{[}`.
Ademas, me parece un poquito complicado. ¿Podría haber sido más simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo recorrería la cadena letra a letra, y para cada carácter encontrado en `lefts` lo guardaría en una "pila", y por cada carácter encontrado en `rights` se intenta extraer el elemento en la cima de la pila (si la pila estuviera vacío, se retornaría `False` pues eso indica que se cierra un grupo sin haberlo abierto). El carácter extraído de la cima de la pila debería ser el que "case" con el que se está procesando. Si no es así, se retorna `False`.

Si se llega al final sin haber detectado error, se comprueba finalmente que la pila haya quedado vacía. Si es así se retorna `True`, y en caso contrario se retorna `False`.

El siguiente código implementa esta idea:

```
def verificar(cadena: str) -> bool:
  pila = []
  lefts = "([{"
  rights = ")]}"

  for c in cadena:
    if c in lefts:
      pila.append(c)
    if c in rights:
      if len(pila) == 0:
        return False
      i = rights.index(c)  # ¿Cuál de los caracteres de cierre es?
      top = pila.pop()     # ¿Cuál era el que estaba abierto?
      if top != lefts[i]:
        return False
  return len(pila) == 0
```

Ejemplos:

```
>>> verificar("([{}[]]())")
True
>>> verificar("((")
False
>>> verificar("(())]")
False
```

**Bonus** Esta función también sirve si la cadena contiene caracteres distintos de esos delimitadores, que serían simplemente ignorados:

```
>>> verificar("[[hola]asdjk](){}[(mundo)x]ff")
True
```